# Ansible - unable to append correctly using the file plugin

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the Ansible `file` plugin to append data to a txt file.

This is my playbook:

```
- name: Setting some variables.
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  
  tasks:
    - name: Delete newDevices file.
      file:
        path: newDevices.txt
        state: absent
      run_once: true

    - name: Create newDevices file.
      file:
        path: newDevices.txt
        state: touch
      run_once: true

    - name: Add new devices to file.
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      lineinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        path: newDevices.txt
        line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

This is my host file:

```
[lab]
routerA01.mgt.net
routerA02.mgt.net
routerB01.mgt.net
routerB02.mgt.net
```

This is how I'm running the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i hosts --limit "lab[0-1]" -e target=lab
```

The **newDevices.txt** file gets deleted and recreated but the contents of the file vary from having 1 hostname or 2 hostnames. If I change the limit in the run command to `--limit "lab[0-2]"` then the same thing happens. Sometimes 2 hostnames will print and other times all 3 will print. Seems like there will always be a time when the newDevices.txt file will contain one less hostname in it.

Not sure why this is happening. Tried adding a pause after the file is created to maybe give the processing a little extra time, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of improvements

1. Put all tasks into a block delegated to localhost. All of them should run only once on the localhost anyway.
2. Then, there is no point to declare global `connection: local`
3. Set `hosts: all` if you plan to limit the inventory on the command line. In this case, there is no point to put the group into a variable.
4. Write the file in a loop. This avoids concurrent writing from multiple instances. (What is probably the main reason for your troubles.)

Given the (simplified) inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[lab]
A01
A02
B01
B02
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - block:
        - file:
            path: newDevices.txt
            state: absent
        - file:
            path: newDevices.txt
            state: touch
        - lineinfile:
            insertafter: EOF
            path: newDevices.txt
            line: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0:1]

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [file] *************************************************************************************
changed: [A01 -> localhost]

TASK [file] *************************************************************************************
changed: [A01 -> localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************
changed: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A01)
changed: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A02)

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
A01: ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> cat newDevices.txt 
A01
A02
```

---

- The above playbook is not idempotent. The file is always recreated. The result is that the files will always keep the hosts from the last play only.
- The simplified playbook below is idempotent. The list of the hosts in the file, however, will be cumulative

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        insertafter: EOF
        path: newDevices.txt
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0:1]

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************
changed: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A01)
changed: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A02)

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
A01: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> cat newDevices.txt 
A01
A02
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0:1]

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************
ok: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A01)
ok: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A02)

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
A01: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0:2]

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************
ok: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A01)
ok: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A02)
changed: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=B01)

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
A01: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> cat newDevices.txt 
A01
A02
B01
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0]

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************
ok: [A01 -> localhost] => (item=A01)

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
A01: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> cat newDevices.txt 
A01
A02
B01
```

- The playbook below is idempotent and the file will keep the list of hosts from the last play only

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: newDevices.txt
        content: |-
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

Comment: This fixed the issue that I was having by looping through ```ansible_play_hosts``` and getting the proper amount of hosts written to the output file.

Comment: i have created a continuation of this post since you got me a step closer to what i'm actually trying to accomplish. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281144/ansible-unable-to-append-correctly-using-the-file-plugin-with-conditional-stat)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to have a play targeting `localhost` itself since the file is to be created on the controller anyway. The file can be created using the "items" of `lab` inventory group.

Something like below:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - file:
        path: newDevices.txt
        state: absent

    - lineinfile:
        path: newDevices.txt
        create: yes
        insertafter: EOF
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['lab'][0:2] }}"
```

In the above example, the file gets created by `lineinfile` task itself. You can also remove/change the list slice of `[0:2]` as per your requirement.

Then run it with:

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i hosts
```