# Ansible - unable to append correctly using the file plugin with conditional statement

Tags: ansible

This post is a continuation of [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255245/ansible-unable-to-append-correctly-using-the-file-plugin/73259880#73259880).

If a certain condition is met then I want to write the current hostname in play to an output file.

The condition is `activeCertData|length == 0` then write the hostname of the current host in play to the output file. I have configured my environment so that currently `activeCertData|length == 0` will always be true for every host this playbook runs against. So I should see all my hosts in the output file. In the future, the above-mentioned condition will be true for some hosts and false for others and I want to make sure I capture the hosts in the output file correctly every time.

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - name: Print certData.json
      debug:
        msg: "{{ certData.json }}"

    - name: Set currentCertSN and currentCertID with JMESPATH
      set_fact:
        activeCertData: "{{ certData.json | json_query('items[?status != `revoked`].{ currentCertID: id, currentCertSN: serialHex, status: status, cn: cn}') }}"
      when: certData.json > 0
              
    - name: Add new devices to file.
      copy:
        dest: newDevices.txt
        content: |-
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['activeCertData']|length == 0 %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

This is my hosts file:

```
[lab]
A01
A02
B01
B02
```

This is how I'm running the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i hosts --limit lab[0]
```

The output of the debug task:

```
TASK [Print certData.json] ***************************************
ok: [A01] => {
    "msg": {
        "items": [
            {
                "application": [
                    {
                        "name": "STAGE", 
                        "uuid": "1234"
                    }
                ], 
                "certType": "CertType.INTERNAL", 
                "cn": "routerA01.mgt.net", 
                "id": 6789, 
                "issuer": "STAGEAUTH", 
                "serialHex": "ABCD1234", 
                "status": "Active-Pending Install", 
                "validityEnd": "2024-08-03T23:38:06+00:00", 
                "validityStart": "2022-08-03T23:28:06+00:00"
            }
        ], 
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, read [mre].

Comment: In the previous Q&A, we found out that in this use case the `lineinfile` task without the loop is a no-go. I replaced it in this question with a working version (and removed the redundant code.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the (simplified) inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[lab]
A01
A02
B01
B02
```

There is a couple of improvements and notes

1. Copy the file instead of using *lineinfile*. The functionality is the same and you run one task only instead of three (file absent, file touch, lineinfile)

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: newDevices.txt
        content: |-
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['activeCertData']|length == 0 %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

2. Then, you don't need the block.
3. The task `Authenticate with API` is irrelevant to this problem and I'll omit it.
4. The task `Get cert Serial Num` is replaced by `set_fact` for testing. For example, given the data

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/certData_dict.yml
certData_dict:
  A01:
    json:
      items:
        - {status: revoked, serialHex: 0xA011, id: 01, cn: A01}
        - {status: revoked, serialHex: 0xA012, id: 02, cn: A01}
  A02:
    json:
      items:
        - {status: active, serialHex: 0xA021, id: 03, cn: A02}
        - {status: revoked, serialHex: 0xA022, id: 04, cn: A02}
  B01:
    json:
      items:
        - {status: active, serialHex: 0xB011, id: 05, cn: B01}
        - {status: revoked, serialHex: 0xB012, id: 06, cn: B01}
  B02:
    json:
      items:
        - {status: active, serialHex: 0xB021, id: 07, cn: B02}
        - {status: revoked, serialHex: 0xB022, id: 08, cn: B02}
```

the task below will set the variable *certData*. Use it for testing, then, replace it with *uri*

```yaml
    - name: Get cert Serial Num
      set_fact:
        certData: "{{ certData_dict[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

5. Declare the variables. The attribute *items* is a reserved word. [Bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables) is needed to reference it.

```yaml
currentCertSN: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                   selectattr('status', 'ne', 'revoked')|
                   map(attribute='serialHex') }}"
activeCertData: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                    json_query(activeCertData_query) }}"
activeCertData_query: '[?status != `revoked`].{currentCertID: id,
                                               currentCertSN: serialHex,
                                               status: status,
                                               cn: cn}'
```

6. The task `set_fact` is needed to 'instantiate' the variables in the dictionary *hostvars*

```yaml
    - name: Set currentCertSN and currentCertID with JMESPATH
      set_fact:
        currentCertSN: "{{ currentCertSN }}"
        activeCertData: "{{ activeCertData }}"
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    currentCertSN: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                       selectattr('status', 'ne', 'revoked')|
                       map(attribute='serialHex') }}"
    activeCertData: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                        json_query(activeCertData_query) }}"
    activeCertData_query: '[?status != `revoked`].{currentCertID: id,
                                                   currentCertSN: serialHex,
                                                   status: status,
                                                   cn: cn}'

  tasks:
    - name: Get cert Serial Num
      set_fact:
        certData: "{{ certData_dict[inventory_hostname] }}"
    - name: Set currentCertSN and currentCertID with JMESPATH
      set_fact:
        currentCertSN: "{{ currentCertSN }}"
        activeCertData: "{{ activeCertData }}"
    - copy:
        dest: newDevices.txt
        content: |-
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['activeCertData']|length == 0 %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0:2]

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [Get cert Serial Num] *******************************************************************
ok: [A01]
ok: [A02]
ok: [B01]

TASK [Set currentCertSN and currentCertID with JMESPATH] *************************************
ok: [A01]
ok: [A02]
ok: [B01]

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [A01 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
A01: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
A02: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
B01: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If you take a look at the data you'll see that only the host `A01` is missing any certificate that is not revoked

```yaml
shell> cat newDevices.txt 
A01
```

The playbook is idempotent.

---

Q: ***"Pasted my certData.json output above. The activeCertData var comes back blank."***

A: The playbook below with your certData.json in vars works as expected

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    certData:
      json:
        items:
        - application:
          - name: STAGE
            uuid: '1234'
          certType: CertType.INTERNAL
          cn: routerA01.mgt.net
          id: 6789
          issuer: STAGEAUTH
          serialHex: ABCD1234
          status: Active-Pending Install
          validityEnd: '2024-08-03T23:38:06+00:00'
          validityStart: '2022-08-03T23:28:06+00:00'
        total: 1
    currentCertSN: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                       selectattr('status', 'ne', 'revoked')|
                       map(attribute='serialHex') }}"
    activeCertData: "{{ certData.json['items']|
                        json_query(activeCertData_query) }}"
    activeCertData_query: '[?status != `revoked`].{currentCertID: id,
                                                   currentCertSN: serialHex,
                                                   status: status,
                                                   cn: cn}'

  tasks:
    - name: Set currentCertSN and currentCertID with JMESPATH
      set_fact:
        currentCertSN: "{{ currentCertSN }}"
        activeCertData: "{{ activeCertData }}"
    - debug:
        var: activeCertData
    - copy:
        dest: newDevices.txt
        content: |-
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['activeCertData']|length == 0 %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit lab[0]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [A01] => 
  activeCertData:
  - cn: routerA01.mgt.net
    currentCertID: 6789
    currentCertSN: ABCD1234
    status: Active-Pending Install
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me write an idempotent playbook. I'm just having an issue replacing my jmes_path statement with your json_query statement. I've pasted my certData.json output above. The ```activeCertData``` var comes back blank for me.

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Make sure you understand what **minimal** means. You're welcome!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I added an example.

Comment: Your second example works perfectly when my data set is defined in the vars section. I'm not sure why ```activeCertData``` comes back blank when I'm grabbing the data from the API call. Tried running the API tasks with ```pre_tasks:``` and the rest inside ```post_tasks``` but that didn't help. Your overall solution worked I'm probably experiencing a one-off case. I will continue to investigate. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Find what is the difference. It's up to you.